# How to create a binary tree

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-tree

I did'nt mean binary search tree.

for example, 
if I insert values 1,2,3,4,5 in to a binary search tree the inorder traversal will give
1,2,3,4,5 as output.

but if I insert the same values in to a binary tree, the inorder traversal should give
4,2,5,1,3 as output.

Binary tree can be created using dynamic arrays in which for each element in index n,
2n+1 and 2n+2 represents its left and right childs respectively.

so representation and level order traversal is very easy here.

but I think, in-order,post-order,pre-order is difficult.

my question is how can we create a binary tree like a binary search tree.
ie. 
have a tree class which contains data, left and right pointers instead of arrays.
so that we can recursively do traversal.

Comment: Is your "binary tree" really a heap?  And if so why do you need in-order traversal?

Comment: Did you Google for "binary tree source"?

Comment: not language specific, not a heap (so its not very useful, i know :-)) 
it is a complete binary tree.

Comment: This question screams CS homework assignment to me hehe.

Comment: He wants a binary tree that is implemented as a flat array, not with pointers.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 27):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a binary tree from an array

```
int[] values = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(values);
```

this should prepopulate the binary tree with the values 1 - 5 as follows:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \
4   5
```

this can be done using the following class:

```
class BinaryTree
{
    int value;
    BinaryTree left;
    BinaryTree right;

    public BinaryTree(int[] values) : this(values, 0) {}

    BinaryTree(int[] values, int index)
    {
        Load(this, values, index);
    }

    void Load(BinaryTree tree, int[] values, int index)
    {
        this.value = values[index];
        if (index * 2 + 1 < values.Length)
        {
            this.left = new BinaryTree(values, index * 2 + 1);
        }
        if (index * 2 + 2 < values.Length)
        {
            this.right = new BinaryTree(values, index * 2 + 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be completely wrong,but doesn't it need some sort of looping or recursion to load the entire array?

Comment: trick part, the index in the array start with 0, so the increment in left will be index*2 +1, and right will be index*2 +2. Normally, people think about start with 1 in the graph drawing, then the increment will be left index*2, right index*2+1

Answer (score 3):

Since I have not received any answers to the question which I asked, I will post my own implementaion of the binary tree using arrays.
now I know that array implementaion is easier than i thought ,but still i dont know how to implement the same using linked lists.

the code is in c#

```
  class BinaryTree
    {
        private static int MAX_ELEM = 100;      //initial size of the array
        int lastElementIndex;
        int?[] dataArray;

        public BinaryTree()
        {
            dataArray = new int?[MAX_ELEM];
            lastElementIndex = -1;
        }

        //function to insert data in to the tree
        //insert as a complete binary tree
        public void insertData(int data)
        {
            int?[] temp;
            if (lastElementIndex + 1 < MAX_ELEM)
            {
                dataArray[++lastElementIndex] = data;
            }
            else
            {  //double the size of the array on reaching the limit
                temp = new int?[MAX_ELEM * 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEM; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = dataArray[i];
                }
                MAX_ELEM *= 2;
                dataArray = temp;
                dataArray[++lastElementIndex] = data;
            }
        }

        //internal function used to get the left child of an element in the array
        int getLeftChild(int index) {
            if(lastElementIndex >= (2*index+1))
                return (2*index + 1);
            return -1;
        }

        //internal function used to get the right child of an element in the array
        int getRightChild(int index) {
            if(lastElementIndex >= (2*index+2))
                return (2*index + 2);
            return -1;
        }
        //function to check if the tree is empty
        public bool isTreeEmpty() {
            if (lastElementIndex == -1)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        //recursive function for inorder traversal
        public void traverseInOrder(int index) {
            if (index == -1)
                return;
            traverseInOrder(getLeftChild(index));
            Console.Write("{0} ", dataArray[index]);
            traverseInOrder(getRightChild(index));
        }

        //recursive function for preorder traversal
        public void traversePreOrder(int index) {
            if (index == -1)
                return;
            Console.Write("{0} ", dataArray[index]);
            traversePreOrder(getLeftChild(index));
            traversePreOrder(getRightChild(index));
        }

        //recursive function for postorder traversal
        public void traversePostOrder(int index) {
            if (index == -1)
                return;
            traversePostOrder(getLeftChild(index));
            traversePostOrder(getRightChild(index));
            Console.Write("{0} ", dataArray[index]);
        }

        //function to traverse the tree in level order
        public void traverseLevelOrder()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPrinting Elements Of The Tree In Ascending Level Order\n");
            if (lastElementIndex == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empty Tree!...press any key to return");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= lastElementIndex; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", dataArray[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The tree class declaration part is, certainly, not the difficulty here. You basically stated exactly how to declare it, in the question:

```
class BinaryTree
{
private:
    int data;
    BinaryTree *left, *right;
};
```

This supports various forms of traversal, like so:

```
void Inorder(const BinaryTree *root)
{
  if(root == 0)
    return;
  Inorder(root->left);
  printf("now at %d\n", root->data);
  Inorder(root->right);
}
```

You should be able to deduce pre- and post-order traversals from that. In a real implementation, the tree would probably be templated to store random data, the traversal routines would be more general (with a user-data input, or perhaps user-supplied per-node callback, or whatever), of course.

Comment: Ok, once we have the tree in the above format .. traversal is easy.
but how to create the tree in the above format
(in binary search tree we can compare elements and put them into left or right accordingly, but here we are not doing any.comparison..we have to build the tree as a complete tree.
please correct me if a am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after source for a comprehensive BinaryTree implementation you can learn from have a look at [The C5 Generic Collection Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/).

Answer (score 1):

```
  class BstNode
    {
        public int data;
        public BstNode(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public BstNode left;
        public BstNode right;
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static BstNode Insert(BstNode root, int data)
        {
            if (root == null) root = new BstNode(data);
            else if (data <= root.data) root.left = Insert(root.left, data);
            else if (data > root.data) root.right = Insert(root.right, data);

            return root;
        }

public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create/insert into BST
            BstNode Root = null;
            Root = Insert(Root, 15);
            Root = Insert(Root, 10);
            Root = Insert(Root, 20);
            Root = Insert(Root, 8);
            Root = Insert(Root, 12);
            Root = Insert(Root, 17);
            Root = Insert(Root, 25);
         }

}
```