# create BT needs a tweak

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

Edit : the code works with this edit but I don't understand as to why it does.

working ideone with edit : http://ideone.com/ESfkrs

Edited code :

```
typedef struct _q{
    int front,rear;
    tree *a[MAX];
}queue; 

void enqueue(queue *q, tree *x){
    if(!q || q->rear==MAX-1 || !x){
        return;
    }
    q->a[++q->rear]=x;
}

tree* dequeue(queue *q){
    if(q->front>q->rear || q->front==MAX){
        return NULL;
    }
    return q->a[q->front++];
}
```

I'v following code for creating a BT out of an array representation.
problem is that in multiple loops of while 1 level of BT nodes don't point to next level. i.e r->l & r->r is lost in transition of loop although the mem is heap allocated & must be retained until the program exits.

I'v spent umpteen hours digging this but to no vain. TIA.

working ideone : http://ideone.com/O4VKCH

```
output :
5   10  20  
5   10  20  
5   10  20  
5   10  20  
5   10  20



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100 

typedef struct _tree{
    int data;
    struct _tree *l,*r;
}tree;

typedef struct _q{
    int front,rear;
    tree a[MAX];
}queue; 

void create_node(tree **rooty,int data){
        (*rooty) = (tree*)calloc(1,sizeof(tree));
        (*rooty)->data=data;
        return;
}

void create_node_bst(tree **rooty,int data){
    if(!(*rooty)) {
        create_node(rooty,data);
    }
    if(data<(*rooty)->data)  create_node_bst(&(*rooty)->l,data);
    if(data>(*rooty)->data)  create_node_bst(&(*rooty)->r,data); 
}

void inorder(tree *root){
    if(!root) return;
    if(root->l) inorder(root->l);
    printf("%d\t",root->data);
    if(root->r) inorder(root->r);
}

void enqueue(queue *q, tree *x){
    if(!q || q->rear==MAX-1 || !x){
        return;
    }
    q->a[++q->rear]=*x;
}

tree* dequeue(queue *q){
    if(q->front>q->rear || q->front==MAX){
        return NULL;
    }
    return &(q->a[q->front++]);
} 

void print_q(queue *q){
    if(!q || q->front>q->rear){
        return;
    }
    int front=q->front;
    printf("+\n");
    while(front<=q->rear){
        printf("%d\t",q->a[front++].data);
    }
    printf("\n-");
} 

void bfs_order(tree *root, queue *q){
     if(!root || !q){
        return;
     }
     printf("%d\t",root->data);

     if(root->l)enqueue(q,root->l);  
     if(root->r)enqueue(q,root->r);

     bfs_order(dequeue(q),q);
} 

void initialise_q(queue **q){
    if(!*q){
        *q = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
        (*q)->front=0;
        (*q)->rear=-1;
        memset((*q)->a,0,MAX*sizeof(int));
    }
} 

tree* create_bt(tree *r, queue *q, int *arr, int len){
    if(!q || !arr) return NULL;
    int i=0,first=1;
    tree *root=NULL, *ret=NULL;

    while(i<len){
        tree *temp_l=NULL, *temp_r=NULL;
        root = dequeue(q);
        if(first){
            ret = root;
            first = 0;
        }
        if(!root) break;

        if(i+1<len) {
            create_node(&temp_l,arr[i+1]);
            enqueue(q,temp_l);
        }
        if(i+2<len) {
            create_node(&temp_r,arr[i+2]);
            enqueue(q,temp_r); 
        }
        if(temp_l) {
            //root->l=temp_l;
            create_node(&(root->l),temp_l->data); <-- Pls focus here
        }
        if(temp_r) {
            //root->l=temp_r;
            create_node(&(root->r),temp_r->data); <-- llly, here.
        }
        inorder(ret); printf("\n"); <-- to demo the output
        i+=2;
    }
    return ret;
} 

int main(void) {
    tree *root = NULL, *temp_t=NULL;
    int arr[]={10,5,20,2,7,8,9,0,1};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(int k=0;k<len;k++){
        //create_node_bst(&root,arr[k]);
    }

    queue *q = NULL, *temp_q=NULL;
    initialise_q(&q);
    initialise_q(&temp_q);

    create_node(&temp_t,arr[0]);
    enqueue(q,temp_t);

    tree *bt = create_bt(root,q,arr,len);
    //bfs_order(bt,temp_q);

    if(root) free(root);
    if(q) free(q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828398/how-to-create-a-binary-tree?rq=1

Comment: @DaveClough, Hi Dave, I also stumbled upon the same link that you mentioned & quickly created a stub but I don't see why this logic should work.

`tree* create_bt1(tree *r, int *arr, int len, int idx){
 create_node(&r,arr[idx]);
 if(2*idx+1<len) create_bt1(&(r->l),arr,len,2*idx+1);
 if(2*idx+2<len) create_bt1(&(r->r),arr,len,2*idx+2);
 return r;
} `

output : 10

Comment: `q->a[++q->rear]=x;`This will write the first entry into `[1]` I think you want postincrement: `q->a[ q->rear++ ]=x;`

Comment: @wildplasser My Q implementation has rear initialised with -1