# How to create a binary tree of value type String

Tags: c#, algorithm

How to create a binary tree of value type String by C#

i don't want binary tree search i just want to make binary tree of value string to do some algorithm like BFS & DFS .. )

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Or do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: i know how to create tree but buy value intger but i don't know how to do this by string

Comment: I guess there is no difference if the value is an int or a string ;) Give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with a simple node class as shown below. Here `Data` represents a `string` value like you've mentioned. You can change this to `int` or any other type.

```
public class BinaryTreeNode
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public BinaryTreeNode Left { get; set; }
    public BinaryTreeNode Right { get; set; }

    public BinaryTreeNode(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

Why don't you start by taking a look at some of these articles

- [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [How to create a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828398/how-to-create-a-binary-tree)